# Magento 2 : Enabling http2_push with Nginx frontserver and varnish

Tags: nginx, magento, http2, pagespeed-insights, magento2.4

I am trying to implement http2_push to get the css sent with all the pages. Here is my sample code. I dont see the css being pushed yet. What am i doing wrong. Http2 is enabled.

```
 location / {
        #add_header Set-Cookie "session=1";
        #add_header Link $push_resources;
        proxy_pass         http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:6081;
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Port 8080;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Country $geoip_country_code;
        http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/css/styles-l.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/StripeIntegration_Payments/css/wallets.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/Magefan_Blog/css/blog-custom.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/Magefan_Blog/css/blog-m.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/css/footer.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/css/font-awesome.min.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/css/header.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/css/archigrafix.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/css/navigationmenu.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/css/theme.min.css;
         http2_push /pub/static/frontend/Archigrafix/basic/en_US/css/styles-m.css;

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Nginx removed push support in 1.25.1: https://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,297538

As did Chrome for reasoned explained in this post (full disclosed, I authored this Chrome post):
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/removing-push/

General consensus is that HTTP/2 Push is too difficult to get right and shouldn’t be used.